# How to extract video track from multi-track MOV video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have a multi-track MOV file and would like to extract one of the video tracks into its own file (or remove the unwanted video track). *Note that I don't want to just extract audio.* I want to extract one of the *video* tracks together with its audio track. I tried VLC but didn't found the way. It does allow you to select video track for playing, but not for exporting. Also looked for `ffmpeg` options, but haven't found a parameter for video tracks.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c copy -map 0:v:0 out.mov
```

to extract the first video track. `0:v:1` for the 2nd one and so forth.